# Cannot hook Click Event from a jTemplate output

Tags: javascript, jquery, jtemplates

When using a foreach from jTemplate, jQuery doesn't hook into the `.click()` event of any DOM Elements within the applied template.

Solutions such as `.live('click', function())` do not work (Partially because .live was deprecated, but the alternative introduced to replace it `.on('click', function())` does the same thing...), and i cannot figure out how to get Click events from the results of a jTemplate.

Thing's i've tried:

- `.live('click', function())`
- `.click(function())`
- `.on('click', function())`
- All 3 events in `$(window).load(function())`, `$(document).ready(function())`, and just freely in a Script tag
- All 3 events before and after calling the `.processTemplate()` function

At this point, i have no more ideas on how to solve this issue.

My jQuery version for reference is 2.1.3, and jTemplate is 0.8.4.

Comment: To delegate event, use e.g: `$(document).on('click', 'selector', handler);`. See documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/  BTW, read: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Thank you A. Wolff, That solved my problem. If you wouldn't mind post that as an Answer so i can mark it as the answer, that would be wonderful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for jQuery 1.7 and above, to delegate event, you should use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method and passing selector parameter.

Here is an example, even it is usally better to bind it to closest static container, not the `document`:

```
$(document).on('click', 'selector', handler);
```

You can as a good read see following link: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/